# How do I unit test(insert) the data provider layer in the Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking

I get a null pointer Exception when I call the insert method on the data provider layer of a unit test. And when call the insert method in the main method in the provider implement file, a null pointer Exception occurs.

Why does null pointer Exception occur? Mapper does not apply @Autowired?

> spring 5.1.6, mybatis 3.5.1, junit 4.12 mockito-core 2.23.4

I tried to create a restful API and check. the insert method works properly.
And I used @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) on testFile.java and used @Mock annotation on the mapper.

Then null pointer exception does not occur, but the value is not stored in the actual database .. (obviously?)

I do not know how to look up the stored value and write a test case.
(The retrieve mapper / insert, update mapper is different.)

DataCollectProviderImpl.java

```
@Component
public class DataCollectProviderImpl implements DataCollectProvider {

    @Autowired
    private DataCollectMapper dataCollectMapper;

    @Override
    public String registerCollectData(HospitalDataCollectionInfo hospitalDataCollectionInfo) {
        dataCollectMapper.insertCollectData(hospitalDataCollectionInfo); <---null pointer exception
        return hospitalDataCollectionInfo.getDataCollectId();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataCollectProvider dcp = new DataCollectProviderImpl();
        HospitalDataCollectionInfo hospitalDataCollectionInfo = new HospitalDataCollectionInfo();
        hospitalDataCollectionInfo.setDataCollectId("Testtttt");
        hospitalDataCollectionInfo.setDiseaseCode("A");
        hospitalDataCollectionInfo.setDataStateCode("1");
        hospitalDataCollectionInfo.setHospitalCode("A");
        hospitalDataCollectionInfo.setCollectedCount(1);
        hospitalDataCollectionInfo.setCollectedCount(1);
        hospitalDataCollectionInfo.setBaseDateTime("123456");
        hospitalDataCollectionInfo.setBaseDateTimeSequence(1);
        hospitalDataCollectionInfo.setCollectEndDateTime("1234");
        hospitalDataCollectionInfo.setCollectStartDateTime("1234");
        hospitalDataCollectionInfo.setCreateDateTime("123");
        hospitalDataCollectionInfo.setUpdateDateTime("123");
        dcp.registerCollectData(hospitalDataCollectionInfo);
    }
}
```

test.java

```
public class DataCollectProviderTest {

    @Autowired
    private DataCollectMapper dataCollectMapper;

    @Test
    public void registerCollectDataTest() {
        HospitalDataCollectionInfo insertData = (HospitalDataCollectionInfo) setClassFields(new HospitalDataCollectionInfo());
        dataCollectMapper.insertCollectData(insertData); <---null pointer exception

    }

    private Object setClassFields(Object object) {
        try {
            Class clazz = object.getClass();
            Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                Field field = fields[i];
                field.setAccessible(true);
                if (field.getType() == Integer.TYPE) {
                    field.set(object, i);
                } else {
                    field.set(object, "Test" + (999 - i));
                }
            }

            return clazz.cast(object);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

i expect that data can be inserted and read data normally.
but null pointer exception occurs on insert method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For Spring:

As [the Spring documentation on testing suggests](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html), auto-wiring and dependency injection in test classes will not function unless you annotate the test class with two separate annotations:

- The JUnit 4 [`@RunWith`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) annotation, using the [`SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html) class:

  ```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  ```
- The Spring [`@ContextConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextConfiguration.html) annotation from the `org.springframework.test` package:

  ```
  @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext_mock.xml" })
  ```

Example usage:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext_mock.xml" })
public class DataCollectProviderTest {
    // ...
}
```

### For Spring Boot:

As [the Spring Boot documentation on testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) suggests, auto-wiring and dependency injection in test classes will not function unless you annotate the test class with two separate annotations:

- The JUnit [`@RunWith`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) annotation, using the [`SpringRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringRunner.html) class:

  ```
  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
  ```
- The [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) annotation from the [`spring-boot-starter-test`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test) Maven dependency:

  ```
  @SpringBootTest
  ```

Example usage:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DataCollectProviderTest {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thnak you but my test environments is not spring boot, it just spring framework..

Comment: I tried to use @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) on testFile.java and use @Mock annotation on the mapper. Then null pointer exception does not occur, but the value is not stored in the actual database .. (obviously?) I do not know how to look up the stored value and write a test case. (The retireve mapper / insert, update mapper is different.)

Comment: Hi @Jays, I've edited my question to reflect this. Sorry, I misread it intially.

Comment: Hi @Paul Benn , 
it's okay. I just appreciate your comments.